# Object.freeze() vs const

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

[`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) seems like a transitional convenience method to move towards using `const` in ES6.

Are there cases where both take their place in the code or is there a preferred way to work with immutable data?

Should I use [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) until the moment all browsers I work with support `const` then switch to using `const` instead?

Comment: I've taken to using [babeljs](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/) in my build process so I can mainly ignore compatibility issues such as these.

Comment: No - they do different things. const prevents reassignment (e.g. you can't const x = 1; x = 2); freeze prevents mutation (e.g. you can't Object.freeze(x); x.a = 2);

Comment: Not sure if it makes sense to make this a new question or just tack it on here but I would also be curious if there any big differences between Symbols and Object.freeze? I feel they are also related (i.e. Symbols are evaluated as frozen from `Object.isFrozen` but they also are their own primitive data type...)

Comment: The mutation is prevented only for the first level so you can't Object.freeze(x); x.a = 2, but you CAN Object.freeze(x); x.a.b = 2.  See https://jsfiddle.net/antimojv/op6ea91w/8/ . For a full freeze use ad hoc libraries

Comment: I think meybe he meant "as const"? And you guys are misinterpreting what the OP actually meant.

Answer (score 323, accepted):

`const` and `Object.freeze` are two completely different things.

`const` applies to **bindings** ("variables"). It creates an immutable binding, i.e. you cannot assign a new value to the binding.

`Object.freeze` works on **values**, and more specifically, *object values*. It makes an object immutable, i.e. you cannot change its properties.

Comment: Basically, `const` is the new `var`; it's just block-scoped and prevents reassignment. You can use `let`, but really only need to if you're going to change the value that a variable points to, which makes sense for loop control/iterator variables and simple types like numbers and strings, but not for most uses of objects (including arrays). If you want an object/array whose contents cannot be changed, then besides declaring it with `const` you should also call `Object.freeze()` on it.

Comment: `const` is NOT the new `var`, `let` is the new `var`

Comment: It seems **Object.freeze** only works on object and **NOT** on values types. e.g. `var age = 33; Object.freeze(age); age=34; //no problem` age can still be changed without any problem.

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib: You are comparing apples and oranges. `Object.freeze` doesn't prevent you from assigning a different value to a variable, that's what `const` is for. Your example will show the same "problem" when you use an object: `var age = {years: 33}; Object.freeze(age); age = {years: 34}; // no problem`. Besides, primitive values are already immutable...

Answer (score 114):

In ES5 `Object.freeze` doesn't work on primitives, which would probably be more commonly declared using `const` than objects. You can freeze primitives in ES6, but then you also have support for `const`.

On the other hand `const` used to declare objects doesn't "freeze" them, you just can't redeclare the whole object, but you can modify its keys freely. On the other hand you can redeclare frozen objects.

`Object.freeze` is also shallow, so you'd need to recursively apply it on nested objects to protect them.

```
var ob1 = {
   foo : 1,
    bar : {
        value : 2   
    }
};
Object.freeze( ob1 );

const ob2 = {
   foo : 1,
    bar : {
        value : 2   
    }
}

ob1.foo = 4;  // (frozen) ob1.foo not modified
ob2.foo = 4;  // (const) ob2.foo modified

ob1.bar.value = 4;  // (frozen) modified, because ob1.bar is nested
ob2.bar.value = 4;  // (const) modified

ob1.bar = 4;  // (frozen) not modified, bar is a key of obj1
ob2.bar = 4;  // (const) modified

ob1 = {};  // (frozen) ob1 redeclared
ob2 = {}; // (const) ob2 not redeclared
```

Comment: This explanation cleared so many of my questions in one sweep! Regarding `ob1.bar.value = 4;  // (frozen) modified, because ob1.bar is nested`: Is it because of the method's scope?

Answer (score 34):

### Summary:

`const` and `Object.freeze()` serve totally different purposes.

- `const` is there for declaring a variable which has to assinged  right away and can't be reassigned. variables declared by `const` are block scoped and not function scoped like variables declared with `var`
- `Object.freeze()` is a method which accepts an object and returns the same object. Now the object cannot have any of its properties removed or any new properties added.

### Examples `const`:

**Example 1: Can't reassign `const`**

```js
const foo = 5;

foo = 6;
```

The following code throws an error because we are trying to reassign the variable foo who was declared with the `const` keyword, we can't reassign it.

**Example 2: Data structures which are assigned to `const` can be mutated**

```js
const object = {
  prop1: 1,
  prop2: 2 
}

object.prop1 = 5;   // object is still mutable!
object.prop3 = 3;   // object is still mutable!

console.log(object);  // object is mutated
```

In this example we declare a variable using the `const` keyword and assign an object to it. Although we can't reassign to this variable called object, we can mutate the object itself. If we change existing properties or add new properties this will this have effect. To disable any changes to the object we need `Object.freeze()`.

### Examples `Object.freeze()`:

**Example 1: Can't mutate a frozen object**

```js
object1 = {
  prop1: 1,
  prop2: 2
}

object2 = Object.freeze(object1);

console.log(object1 === object2); // both objects are refer to the same instance

object2.prop3 = 3; // no new property can be added, won't work

delete object2.prop1; // no property can be deleted, won't work

console.log(object2); // object unchanged
```

In this example when we call `Object.freeze()` and give `object1` as an argument the function returns the object which is now 'frozen'. If we compare the reference of the new object to the old object using the `===` operator we can observe that they refer to the same object. Also when we try to add or remove any properties we can see that this does not have any effect (will throw error in strict mode).

**Example 2: Objects with references aren't fully frozen**

```js
const object = {
  prop1: 1,
  nestedObj: {
    nestedProp1: 1,
    nestedProp2: 2,
  } 
}


const frozen = Object.freeze(object);

frozen.prop1 = 5; // won't have any effect
frozen.nestedObj.nestedProp1 = 5; //will update because the nestedObject isn't frozen

console.log(frozen);
```

This example shows that the properties of nested objects (and other by reference data structures) are **still mutable**. So `Object.freeze()` doesn't fully 'freeze' the object when it has properties which are references (to e.g. Arrays, Objects).

Comment: Nice explanation

Answer (score 14):

Let be simple.

**They are different. Check the comments on the code, that will explain each case.**

**`Const`** - It is block scope variable like `let`, which value can not reassignment, re-declared .

That means

```
{
 const val = 10;  // you can not access it outside this block, block scope variable

}

console.log(val); // undefined because it is block scope 

const constvalue = 1;
constvalue = 2; // will give error as we are re-assigning the value;
const obj = { a:1 , b:2};

obj.a = 3;
obj.c = 4;
console.log(obj); // obj = {a:3,b:2,c:4} we are not assigning the value of identifier we can 
                  // change the object properties, const applied only on value, not with properties
obj = {x:1};     // error you are re-assigning the value of constant obj 
obj.a = 2 ;     // you can add, delete element of object
```

**The whole understanding is that const is block scope and its value is not re-assigned.**

**`Object.freeze`:**
The object root properties are unchangeable, also we can not add and delete more properties but we can reassign the whole object again.

```
var x = Object.freeze({data:1,
    name:{
    firstname:"hero", lastname:"nolast"
    }
});

x.data = 12;  // the object properties can not be change but in const you can do
x.firstname ="adasd"; // you can not add new properties to object but in const you can do

x.name.firstname = "dashdjkha"; // The nested value are changeable 

//The thing you can do in Object.freeze but not in const

x = { a: 1};  // you can reassign the object when it is Object.freeze but const its not allowed
```

// One thing that is similar in both is, nested object are changeable

```
const obj1 = {nested :{a:10}};
var obj2 =  Object.freeze({nested :{a:10}});

obj1.nested.a = 20; // both statement works
obj2.nested.a = 20;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

```
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
Object.freeze(obj);
obj.newField = 3; // You can't assign new field , or change current fields
```

The above example it completely makes your object immutable.

Lets look following example.

```
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
obj.a = 13; // You can change a field
obj.newField = 3; // You can assign new field.
```

It won't give any error.

But If you try like that

```
const obj = {
      a: 1,
      b: 2
    };
obj = {
 t:4
};
```

It will throw an error like that "obj is read-only".

Another use case

```
const obj = {a:1};
var obj = 3;
```

It will throw `Duplicate declaration "obj"`

Also according to mozilla docs [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) explanation

> The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. **It
>   does not mean the value it holds is immutable**, solely that the
>   variable identifier can not be reassigned.

*This examples created according to babeljs ES6 features.*

Answer (score -1):

in ES6 const is more used than before and you cant define it again with another value you encounter an Error, on the other hand if you make an object freez you cant change or define its properties again, you face an Error again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).