# How can I use enum values as index of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, enums, array-indexing

I try to use enum value as index of array but it gives me an error.

```
export class Color {
    static RED = 0;
    static BLUE = 1;
    static GREEN = 2;
}

let x = ['warning', 'info', 'success'];
let anotherVariable = x[Color.RED]; <---- Error: Type 'Color' cannot be used as an index type.
```

I tried Number() and parseInt to convert to number but it does not work.

Is there any way that I can use Enum values as an index?

Comment: Thats not an enum. And `Color.RED` is not an instance of `Color`.

Comment: Works for me in plain JS in Chrome if I remove the export keyword

Comment: @mplungjan same here. But not in firefox - it reports that fields are not yet supported.

Comment: It only shows this error when you have `x[Color]` instead of `x[Color.RED]` [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2J4CdoG8BQ1vQgFzDwEthoAlAUQBFoBeaABgG4sd9CToAhAGQFUKdaAEYWOXAWKkA4pQoA5IQCYWAXwwYQAUzzQAHkIDaAcgDuYZADsilgObGANNGM2AZvEfOIAV2DAtUMYAuizaumCW8HgAFlrIAGoWRGAARtpCeoYISMghQA)

Answer (score 2):

To create an Enum we create a const frozen object. For the difference and why see the below quote:

> const applies to bindings ("variables"). It creates an immutable
>   binding, i.e. you cannot assign a new value to the binding.
>
> Object.freeze works on values, and more specifically, object values.
>   It makes an object immutable, i.e. you cannot change its properties.

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33128023/9758920

Afterwards we can still access the keys and values like with a normal object.

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287903/what-is-the-preferred-syntax-for-defining-enums-in-javascript
const COLORS = Object.freeze({"RED":0, "BLUE":1, "GREEN":2})

let x = ['warning', 'info', 'success'];
let anotherVariable = x[COLORS.RED]; 

console.log(anotherVariable)
```

Also check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49309248/9758920

Comment: This doesn't answer why the posted code is throwing the error

Comment: As seen from the comments: very likely a browser support problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    let color = {
        RED : 0,
        BLUE : 1,
        GREEN : 2
    }

    module.exports = color

    let x = ['warning', 'info', 'success'];
    let anotherVariable = x[color.RED];
```